# Sending parameters values to DataSetProvider

Tags: database, delphi, server, datamodule

I am using DataModule on the server which contains ADOConnection, ADOQuery and DataSetProvider. In ADOQuery SQL property I specify a query with a several parameters. In client application through the ClientDataSet I want to send a **several** input parameters to the server's data set. I know how to send only one parameter as described in the code  below:

```
with ClientDataSet1 do
Data:= DataRequest(Edit1.Text);
Open;
```

How can I specify several query input parameters (e.g. Edit1.Text and Edit2.Text) in DataRequest function? Thanks!

Comment: The parameters in the query will be transferred to the CDS when you right-click and choose "Fetch parameters". Then you can use CDS.Params.ParambyName('param1').AsString := Edit1.Text and so on. All the values will be passed via the DSP to the Query.

Comment: @nolaspeaker, as a result, DataRequest function doesn't required there, right?

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense to me, so all I can tell you is the way that I usually pass parameter values from the CDS to the Query. The method I described also works if the Query is in a Datasnap server.

Comment: @nolaspeaker, ok, then I should specify the same parameters in CDS and in Query "parameters" property, isn't it?

Comment: You don't have to do it by code. You can do it at designtime. Right click on the CDS and choose "fetch parameters" from the context menu.

Comment: @nolaspeaker, ok, I understand. I will try it, thanks

Comment: @nolaspeaker I tried your method, it works, but is it really good practise? Imagine the situation when names of parameters and their count in query on the server will be changed, so remote client app willn't know about this changes. it will fetch parameters but try to find old names of parameters through the ParamByName method. Client app cann't know names of server query parameters, right? Is there any way to cope with described situation?

Comment: The idea here is that you have 1 CDS for each query. Connection->query->provider->CDS. It is very difficult to have changeable queries that also supply read-write data to CDS by this mechanism.

Comment: ok, thanks for explanations!

Comment: There are ways to do this. It's just not possible to explain how to do it in the comments to a question. Ask another SO question. Show us what you tried to do.